# Best Memory Usage

Tags: arrays, io

First Of all thanks for stopping by and here is my qusetion.

I'm working on a project where i use an array that contains much information (About 300 variables every variable is about 25 Characters).So my question here is What is the best way to store it...??
I Have two possible way and please tell me which is better...

**First Way :** Make a normal local where i can store all the needed information and of course it will be stored on the RAM (As far as I Know).

**Second Way :** To store them in a file and whenever i need the array i simply read the data form the file and get the array.

Note That : The array is used occasionally and not every time.

My Second Question is :

Is there a possible error that may occur to the Hard Drive if i made the program write and read so many time in a short period of time.And if so what is the min period i can write and read safely without any possible error...???

Thanks In Advance

Comment: 300 25 character strings is not 'a lot of information' at all. You can safely keep it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing files are **very** slow operation in comparison to RAM access. 300 strings with 25 elements each wouldn't consume too much space with modern RAM. If you need access to this data rarely (once per 10 minutes or once per hour), you, probably, could keep this data on HDD, but, to my opinion, it will be simpler for you to keep it in RAM for all the time.

You can find an answer to your second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711013/can-excessive-hard-disk-usage-degrade-hard-drives).

Comment: Thanks For your help

Answer (score 0):

This data you have mentioned can be easily stored in memory without any memory crash. If there is need to store much larger amount of data, then NSKeyedArchiver (used to stored object in any format in NSData form to disk) can be used or CoreData framework can also be used. CoreData framework also supports caching and it is faster http://nshipster.com/nscoding/. Hope this helps.